# iOS: How to create a bitmap from binary data and save it on the device as image?

Tags: iphone, ios, bitmap, binary-data

I'm trying to create an image by using binary data that I received from a server. In my function I parse through the data and get a color code for every pixel of my symbol (usually 16 x 16).

For now I got this far:

```
- (void)saveSymbol:(Byte *)symbolData WithID:(short)symbolID AndOffset:(int)offset AndLength:(int)length {    

int w, width, h, heigth;

width = [self byteToUShort:symbolData withOffset:offset+6];
heigth = [self byteToUShort:symbolData withOffset:offset+8];

NSLog(@"Symbol with ID:%d\nwidth: %d\nheigth:%d", symbolID, width, heigth);

NSString *docDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];    
NSLog(@"%@", docDir);

NSString *pngFilePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/symbol%d.png", docDir, symbolID];
NSLog(@"%@", pngFilePath);

int pos = 25;

for (h = 0; h < heigth; h++) {
    for (w = 0; w < width; w++) {
        if ((symbolData[pos] & 0xFF) != 255) {
            NSLog(@"set color to %d at point (%d / %d)", symbolData[pos] & 0xFF, w, h);
        }
        else {
            if (symbolID == 9)
                NSLog(@"set color to 253 at point (%d / %d)", w, h);
            else
                NSLog(@"set color to %d at point (%d / %d)", symbolData[pos] & 0xFF, w, h);
        }
        pos += 2;
    }
}
```

}

I hope this made clear what I'm trying to do.

But I don't really know where to go from here. How can I create a bitmap from that data? Is it better to save it as a bitmap or maybe as a png or jpeg file?

Your help will be much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use either a [Bitmap context](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_context/dq_context.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH203-CJBHBFFE) (or CGLayer).
2. After you've drawn your pixels, use `CGBitmapContextCreateImage` to get a CGImageRef.
3. Convert to a UIImage with `[UIImage imageFromCGImage:]`.
4. Then use `UIImagePNGRepresentation()` or `UIImageJPEGRepresentation()` to get an NSData object.
5. Finally use `[NSData writeToFile:atomically:]` to save the file.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. This seems to be quite helpful. But how do I actually add the pixels with different colors to the context?

Comment: I think you may be able to store your pixels in the byte array that you pass as the first argument to `CGBitmapContextCreateImage`, but I'm not entirely certain.

Answer (score 0):

With only pixel data, you have a little project ahead of you.  The standard formats can be complex, especially something like jpeg that has more sophisticated compression.  I think [png is probably the simplest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics).